# Copy a file from one server folder to another folder using webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I am using a webservice to accept a URL of an already uploaded file
and want to copy this file (which is in one server with public access) to another server folder

issue is that when Server.Mappath is used, it is always referring to the web Service project location and not to the URL's location.

Is there anyway that I can copy the file using webservice with the URL only?

Answer (score 0):

if the file is located in a different web site than the webservice, then you have to tell your webservice where are the files located. You could put a key in web.config for this location and then compose the filename:

```
Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilesPath"],fileName);
```

Be aware that you have to have access rights to that folder.